# What are the AI features of Watson Assistant?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot

It is hard to tell from IBM's documentation but what features of Watson Assistant are actually based on AI?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Features based on NLU (Natural Language Understanding) that they named, also known as NLP(Natural Language Processing) in AI field. Using this service we can implement chatbot or other AI based app.